# Angular directive function with unknown number of parameters

Tags: angularjs, function, angularjs-directive, parameters

I would like to use a directive like this :

```
<my-directive some-method="method(arg0, arg1)"></my-directive>
```

And the directive looks like :

```
angular.module('module').directive('myDirective', directive);

   function directive() {
        return {
            restrict:'E',
            scope: {
                someMethod: '&'
            },
            template:'<div ng-click="someMethod()"></div>'
        };
    };
```

I would like to call `method(arg0, arg1)` when I call `someMethod()`. Is it possible ?

Comment: Have you tried to implement the code and test it?

Comment: Yes, it calls `method()` but without parameters. So I expect some tricks to make this work

Comment: It's possible, but you have to work on your arguments in the function definition. Btw it's not possible the way you do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have should work depending on the version of angular you are using.  See http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/b7btgudo/

Notice that there is no need to bind the arguments.  See the console log for the output.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller("myCtrl", myCtrl)
.directive('myDirective', directive);

   function directive() {
        return {
            restrict:'E',
            scope: {
                someMethod: '&'
            },
            template:'<div ng-click="someMethod()">Click Here</div>'
        };
    }

    function myCtrl($scope){
      $scope.myMethod = console.log.bind(console);
      $scope.something = "something";
      $scope.somethingElse = "somethingElse";
    }
```

Simple HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <my-directive some-method="myMethod(something, somethingElse)"></my-directive>
</div>
```

If you are using ControllerAs syntax, you need to make sure you are putting the 'scoped' functions/vars on `this` and use the dot-notation in the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the two parameters as attributes in the template. You can access these two parameters in directive link function. The example below I just display these two parameters in the console.

My suggestion: You don't need to pass the function **someMethod**, you can define a **someMethod** function in the directive. Check commented code in the link session.

Directive:

```
angular.module('module').directive('myDirective', directive);

function directive() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
            someMethod: '&',
            firstArg: '=',
            secondArg: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
          console.log(scope.firstArg);
          console.log(scope.secondArg);

          /*  function someMethod( arg0, arg1) {
           *  implement the someMethod based on your logic.  
           *
           *  }
           */
        },
        template:'<div ng-click="someMethod()"></div>
    };
};
```

HTML:

```
<my-directive some-method="method" firstArg="arg0" secondArg="arg1"></my-directive>
```

Comment: This could works, but in my real case, the number of parameters is unknow. So I could do this on my scope
`scope : {
   someMethod:'&',
   args : '='
}`
where args is an array of arguments. 
But I prefer not to do this if possible

Comment: Then that's another case, you should mention in the question with unknown number of parameters.